# What does it mean for a curve to be immersed (and embedded)?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, curves

From what I understand, a plane curve $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $\alpha'$ is everywhere injective.

An embedding of a plane curve $\alpha: \mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ would be a function $f: I \to \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $f$ is bijective, continuous and has a continuous inverse.

Is my understanding correct? Can anyone provide some examples or some motivation to the definitions? I'm a little lost here, and some clarification would be great.

Comment: An embedding doesn't have to be bijective, but it should be homeomorphic onto its image.

Comment: Your example is wrong. An immersion has nowhere-zero tangent vector. It certainly need not be one-to-one, so what you checked isn't relevant. You need to compute $\alpha'(t)$ and see it's never the zero vector.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I meant to write $\alpha'(\frac{\pi}{3})$, not  $\alpha(\frac{\pi}{3})$. I computed $\alpha'(t)$ and saw that it is the zero vector at $t = \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$, so it is not an immersion, correct?

Comment: I think you're wrong. I think this curve is an immersion (but crosses itself). Better check your computation.

Comment: I checked my computation, it was wrong indeed. I'll take this example out of my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immersion is as you say a differentiable map $\alpha : I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that its derivative $\alpha'$ is injective at each point of the domain.

Why is this important? As far as I know, immersions become more relevant in the context of manifolds (of which curves are a special case). In general, if you have a map $f :  M \to N$ between manifolds which is an immersion, it means the derivative $df_x :  T_x M \to T_{f(x)}N$ is injective at each point $x \in M$. One reason this property is nice is that given an immersion $f$, for  each $x  \in M$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ such that $f(U)$ is an immersion.

This does not mean that $f(M)$ in its entirety is a manifold (though this could happen). If $f :M \to N$ is an embedding, it means it is an immersion, and also a homeomorphism onto its image (in particular, injective). In this case, we get the full conclusion  that $f(M)$ is a manifold.